# Is there an option to disable specific jars when using spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I am running the jar file through spark-submit. (yarn, client mode)
When running the jar, the library installed in the class path in the spark cluster server is used.
However, I get an error because of version dependencies between certain libraries.
I don't want to change a component in the server classpath. Because it can be used elsewhere.

So the question is, is there an option to disable certain libraries on spark cluster server only when running spark-submit?
or is there any other way to solve my problem?

I look forward to your reply. thank you.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do in your jar is called shading your classes. You can shade the class that is being affected by the class path. https://medium.com/@akhaku/java-class-shadowing-and-shading-9439b0eacb13

Comment: Thank you for answer. I found the maven shade plugin, and I am trying with uber jar.
I have one question, where can I check the library information actually used by spark-submit? I want to check the jar file actually used by the Datanode.